# How to make patch not so strict?

Tags: git, subversion, patch

To give you the background, I'm trying to "port" "commit only parts of hunks" workflow from `git` to `svn`.

In `git` there is interactive staging, and you can even edit hunks to be committed (chose which parts of hunks to commit, or even commit something that wasn't in the hunk initially). In `svn` there's no such thing, but you can `diff`/`patch`.

Now let's do some tests. The first script creates a repository with one commit, edits the file and runs interactive staging:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
rm -rf 1   # !!! it removes dir `1`
mkdir 1
cd "$_"
git init
echo 'aaa
bbb' > 1
git add 1
git ci -am c1
sed -i 's/aaa/aaa\n111\n222\n333/' 1
git add -p
git --no-pager diff
git --no-pager diff --cached
```

Run the script, and when asked what to do with the hunk, chose "edit", remove line "+222", and exit the editor. You will see:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/yuri/_/1/1/.git/
[master (root-commit) 1274f4f] c1
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 1
diff --git a/1 b/1
index dbee026..5c89250 100644
--- a/1
+++ b/1
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 aaa
+111
+222
+333
 bbb
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? e

diff --git a/1 b/1
index f1dea50..5c89250 100644
--- a/1
+++ b/1
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 aaa
 111
+222
 333
 bbb
diff --git a/1 b/1
index dbee026..f1dea50 100644
--- a/1
+++ b/1
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 aaa
+111
+333
 bbb
```

The second script creates similar patch, removes line "+222" and tries to apply the resulting patch:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
rm -rf 2   # !!! it removes dir `2`
mkdir 2
cd "$_"
echo 'aaa
bbb' > 1
echo 'aaa
111
222
333
bbb' > 2
diff -u 1 2 > 1.patch || true
cat 1.patch
sed -En -i '/\+222/!p' 1.patch
cat 1.patch
patch -p0 < 1.patch
```

But it fails:

```
--- 1   2015-12-04 21:52:58.815274483 +0200
+++ 2   2015-12-04 21:52:58.815274483 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 aaa
+111
+222
+333
 bbb
--- 1   2015-12-04 21:52:58.815274483 +0200
+++ 2   2015-12-04 21:52:58.815274483 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 aaa
+111
+333
 bbb
patching file 1
patch: **** malformed patch at line 7:
```

Is there a way to make it work without manually editing `@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@` parts?